# How do I start gmapping with an initial map?

Tags: slam, navigation, slam-gmapping, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How do I give gmapping an initial map to start with?

My maps don't always turn out great, and it takes a long time to build them.  I'd like to be able to map part of the house, when that looks good, save that map, and start again from there.

([This tutorial](http://www.ros.org/wiki/turtlebot_navigation/Tutorials/Autonomously%20navigate%20in%20a%20known%20map) shows how to use a known map for AMCL, but not as a starting point for gmapping).

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/54394/how-do-i-start-gmapping-with-an-initial-map?/) by [Jon Stephan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2281/jon-stephan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 837 on 2013-02-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Short answer: Not possible.

Longer answer: http://answers.ros.org/question/37486/modifying-a-known-map-gmapping/ and the links inside

---

Originally posted by [weiin](https://answers.ros.org/users/1505/weiin/) with karma: 2268 on 2013-02-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Jon Stephan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2281/jon-stephan/) on 2013-02-05**:
Ah, but that gives me an idea.  You could patch two maps together with gimp to make one bigger map.

**Comment by [weiin](https://answers.ros.org/users/1505/weiin/) on 2013-02-05**:
yes, you can then use amcl to localise on that map.

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-02-05**:
Any gimp-like stuff is fine as long as the geometry stays intact. You could even correct the maps there.